# Is any of the Skitty family catchable in either X or Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I'm looking to catch a Skitty, and eventually breed it then get a Delcatty. [I've read Skitty is catchable on Route 4](http://www.neoseeker.com/forums/60943/t1910333-has-anybody-found-skitty-on/), but after an hour or two of trying I couldn't find one. I understand X&Y has only been out for a short while, however I figured some somebody is bound to come across it if it is in the game.

So, if Skitty (or Delcatty) is catchable which route or area is it available in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Skitty is definitely catchable in Pokemon X & Y. It doesn't seem to matter whether you're running around in Yellow/Red flowers or Plain grass.

Here's a video of someone running into Skitty on Route 4. He's having more trouble finding Ralts it seems. Skip ahead to about 2:20

Answer (score 2):

[Skitty](http://serebii.net/pokedex-xy/300.shtml) is available in both X & Y. As you've uncovered elsewhere, it is found on [Route 4](http://serebii.net/pokearth/kalos/route4.shtml), which type of flowers (red or yellow) or grass you trample through does not seem to matter. However, exact encounter rates for the various routes don't seem to be completely worked out yet.

Comment: So just try in the flowers, and **not** the grass? I guess the flower beds are my best bet.

Comment: @user56652 - It doesn't seem to matter, flowers and grass (on the same Route) appear to give the same Pokemon

Comment: They probably have different encounter rates though, so switching after you've had no luck for a while might be a good idea.